# Fiji Airways lounge access: can I take my child for free?

Tags: children, lounges, fiji

Flying to NZ from the US, have a 4 or 5 hour stop in Fiji.  Am considering paying for lounge passes for myself and my wife, just wondering if we would also need to pay for one for our 9yo so we can all use the lounge, or if the child would be allowed in accompanying my wife and myself?  We're not business class or status members, just flying economy and looking to pay extra for the lounge pass for this one trip.  I can't see anything one way or the other on the Fiji Airways website.

Do I need to pay for a child to join us in the lounge if two adults have purchased passes?

Comment: many lounges don't allow children, either for noise reasons or because of the liquor license. Check that first.

Comment: @KateGregory the lounge has a kids play area and games/tv room so my assumption is they allow kids

Comment: @KateGregory I've double checked - they definitely allow kids! But thanks for the prompt, I hadn't considered that

Comment: [the Fiji Airways website](https://www.fijiairways.com/experience/fiji-airways-premier-lounge) says that "Tabua Club" members can bring children for free, which sort of implies that other people can not, but it's quite vague, and possibly you might get lucky and convince the desk agent to let your child in with two paid adults even if the official policy says no